# Django template - number between?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do an if statement in a Django template for if a number is greater than 75 but less than 90, I'm not sure how this is done in a template, below is my code thus far, which errors:-

Error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '<=90' from '<=90'
```

Code:

```
<td>
    <span class="
    {% if i.speed_down >= 90 %}
    red
    {% elif i.speed_down >= 75 <=90 %}
    amber
    {% endif %}
    ">
        Speed Down: {{ i.speed_down }}
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: `{% elif i.speed_down >= 75 <=90 %}` shouldn't it be `{% elif 75<= i.speed_down  <=90 %}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
{% elif i.speed_down >= 75 and i.speed_down <= 90 %}
```

However, in this case simply checking against 75 should be enough, since you will only ever reach your `elif` statement if i.speed_down is < 90, otherwise you would have entered the block of the `if` before that.

Be careful however, you seem to be ambiguous on what to do when i.speed_down is exactly 90?

Best of luck!

Comment: this worked, only thing needed was a space between <= and 90

Comment: yes, you're right, sorry. for code aesthetics, not for correctness however. :-)

fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: without the space I got a remainder error, thanks for your help though